# Multiresolution modifier not working

Tags: modifiers

[image]When I try to increase the preview, sculpt, or render, it does not work. How do I fix it to make them increase? I already have the subdivision surface in the modifier stack.

Comment: What method are you using to try and increase the preview level? Are you clicking the 'Subdivide' button on the multiresolution modifier and it's not doing anything?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot I can not press the subdivide button because it won't let me click it. I can't because it is not available. Plus I cannot see a warning...

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a screenshot or a .blend?

Comment: @KeshaWilson Are you in edit mode? Try switching to object mode

Comment: @gandalf3 Okay I got it to work, but is it normal that I cannot see the sculpting in edit mode after I sculpt it with the multiresolution modifier? Or do you have to apply it?

Comment: @KeshaWilson That's normal. You can still edit the mesh in edit mode have have it affect the sculpted mesh, but you won't be able to see your changes in real time..

Comment: @gandalf3 you want to put an answer on this one? I'll do it if you don't want to... *cough*" ahem."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multires modifier doesn't allow you to subdivide while in edit mode. Try switching to a different mode (e.g. object mode).

Note that you can still edit the base mesh in edit mode after subdividing (your changes will even affect the higher subdivisions), but you won't be able to see the affect on the higher poly mesh in real time.