# Can't change Preview, Sculpt, Render in Multires modifier while in object mode?

Tags: uv, modifiers, texture-baking

I have the same exact issue as this question but I am in object mode not in edit mode so how can I fix this?

[Multiresolution modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30655/multiresolution-modifier-not-working)

[image]

I'm new to this, first time messing with this panel following cgcookie tutorial so please go easy on me.

Comment: So what's the problem? The Subdivide button of the Multires mod doesn't appear to be greyed out, did you try to use it? Note that all the subdivisions are set to 0 so you won't see effect of the modifier as of now but you should once there's at least 1 subdivision.

Comment: @ Mr Zak Sorry I don't understand what you mean when you said "try to use it", if I click on apply the panel just disappears, when input numbers into the 3 panels(Preview,  Sculpt, and Render) then press enter they just resets back to 0.

Comment: Those numbers shouldn't be edited by hand, they are used once at least one subdivision was added. In order to add subdivision press Subdivide button. Apply is complete another story, it makes changes made with modifier real and modifier will no longer be in stack.